# ReactJS: Separating Components Best Practices

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So, I have a react-bootstrap nav and I want to have one of the nav items open and close a bootstrap modal component.

I have this working with this:

```
import React, { Component, render } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class NavigationBar extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
 this.state = {
  showModal: false
 } 
}
close() { this.setState({ showModal: false }); }
open() { this.setState({ showModal: true }); }
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar>
      ...entire navbar...
    </Navbar>
    <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={() => this.close()}>

      ...entire modal... which would be nice to put if a different file

    </Modal>
  </div>
); } }
```

Ideally, I would like to put the modal in a different component file and import it in, but when I do, I'm lost on how to translate the navbar open and close.

What is the best practice for combining components while maintaining their state across files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to think about it is containers vs presentational components. Containers hold your state and most of your logic. Presentational components take in inputs (props) and render html (jsx) [and do little else].

So, you could make your own Modal component that takes in the methods to call on close and one on whether or not it's shown. It could even be a stateless component - if it's just props + jsx, no need for a full class structure:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const MyModal = ({ show, onHide}) => (
  <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>

    // ...entire modal...

  </Modal>
);

// displayName and propTypes are always good to have
MyModal.displayName = 'MyModal';
MyModal.propTypes = {
  show: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  onHide: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
export default MyModal;
```

then to use it, you will need to make sure to bind your methods so they're called in the right context:

```
class NavigationBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };

    // this is the important binding
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  }
  close() { this.setState({ showModal: false }); }
  open() { this.setState({ showModal: true }); }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar>
          // ...entire navbar...
        </Navbar>
        <MyModal
          show={this.state.showModal} 
          onHide={this.close}
        >
          // child content if needed (unless it's all defined in MyModal)
        </Modal>
      </div>
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: We posted at the same time but your answer is a lot more detailed. +1!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your react-bootstrap Modal with your content into your own custom component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const NewModal = ({show, onHide}) => {
  <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
    Modal content in here
  </Modal>
};

export default NewModal;
```

And then import that modal from your component file

```
import Modal from 'components/modal' // Import your new modal's default export
```